# Do debugging information reveal code in C++ / MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, exe

If we distribute a compiled C++ executable which contains debug information/symbols does this enable a third party to learn more about the source code from which the program was compiled than if debug information were missing?

- "learn more" => get information about names of functions, variables, classes, etc.
- Assuming of course that no Debug-Symbol file (.pdb) was shipped

This question relates mostly to protection of proprietary code in C++ as compiled with MSVC, but information about other compilers and debug symbols in general may provide insights as well.

Some context for the question: We ship executables with debug information to create stack traces in case of unexpected program state.

EDIT: We maintain the PDBs inside our company, of course, to be able to read the stack traces once they arrive.

Comment: If they do not have the PDB files, they cannot step into or debug the code. They will, however, get annoying Asserts if the dlls were built in debug.

Comment: Surely they'll be able to step in via the debug, it'll just be in assembler, with some basic (if not impenetrable) data around. If you work really hard you can work out some bit's and pieces, I think that's how some of the Visual Studio 6.0 extensions where written. If you can remember that far back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no. All debug information is stored in the PDB and the EXE just contains the path to the PDB.

If you are concerned, you can always use a hex editor to browse through the binary code to see what information is embedded in the .EXE. This is something I tend to do whenever I build for a new platform or with a new set of dev tools. Sometimes you get things embedded that you don't really want, but usually not about the code, more like network names and paths.

Comment: Yes I agree, I also look as the resources too (for Win32 apps) sometimes some unexpected artifacts can be left in too.

Comment: But the OP says that they are generating stack traces using debug information but without the PDB. This appears to contradict the assertion that "all" debug information is in the PDB.

Comment: I may be wrong but I assumed the OP meant they were generating a dump file which is a snapshot of the stack and other information in memory, which doesn't require any special debug information in the exe.

Answer (score 2):

I only know about Microsoft compilers....
The PDB would store extra information (You should really strip your pdb, if you really care.)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd.aspx

John Robbins has written some great articles on PDBs and how to use them, here is a start
http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know
Hope that get's you going...

Comment: Thanks for the links! I like the idea to use a Symbol server and link it up with SVN. Yet, http://blog.aaronballman.com/2012/05/source-indexing-svn-repositories-is-broken/

Comment: I have used a symbol server, and also just stored the symbols by hand, However my production code is not so important that I really need to stip the PDBs, I guess that yours is, and that'll add a load of complexity on the infrasture.

Comment: We keep copies of all the PDBs packaged with the release executables on an archive drive. So this is not so much a problem (a good Continuous Integration tool, should do this job for you). But we must go back to the code revision manually to have a look what a stack trace really means.

Comment: When I build a production version, I use a post-build step to push the code, executables and debug symbols to a special production repository, and then add some metadata with the revision id to an xml file that is shipped with the product. Then I use a crash reporting application to generate a crash dump, package the dump file with the xml file and any other necessary data, and send it to a crash report server. Then I have a custom tool that will check out the revision from the production repo, open any other user data, and kick off a debug session. Very convenient for me.

Answer (score 1):

The executable contains the code for the program. With enough determination, it can be reconstructed (look around for discussions of how some computer virus works, there you'll see that people who just got the executable, in many cases even encrypted and otherwise obfuscated to make recognizing it as malware more difficult, figured out how it works).

Besides, it is easier just to copy the executable, why bother finding out how it is written to write a clone...