# debugger: How to get address of class name in constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, immediate-window

NOTE: I'm not trying to solve a programming problem; I'm trying to learn.

Given this c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

class class1
{
    public:
        int attr1 = 12;
        class1()
        {

        }   // breakpoint
};

int main()
{
    class1 c1;
}
```

Using VS2019; breakpoint set per above.
In Immediate Window:

```
this
0x000000877f54fcf4 {attr1=0x0000000c }
    attr1: 0x0000000c

attr1
0x0000000c

class1::attr1
0x0000000c

&(class1::attr1)    (am able to use "class1" here, I assume, because it's clear I'm not referring to a typename)
0x000000877f54fcf4 {0x0000000c}

class1        (returns blank line?)


&class1       (treats class1 as type)
type name is not allowed
```

Also, in Memory window, entering "class1" in `Address` field shows:
Unable to evaluate the expression.

At the breakpoint, my questions:

1. How can I get the address of class1 in the immediate window by using
   the identifier "class1"?  (yes, I know it's the same address as
   "this")
2. Same question re: Memory window
3. Why does "class1" in Immediate Window return blank?

[image]

Comment: Types don't have addresses. You may be looking for the address of `c1` which is an instance of `class1`.

Comment: You should use the object `c1` instead. Note that you also used `attr1` and not `int`.

Comment: class names do not exist at runtime. [They are not objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object). They have no size or address.

Comment: @user4581301 Classes do have a size though.

Comment: OK. They have size, they do not require storage.

Comment: _(yes, I know it's the same address as "this")_ no, that's wrong. A class define a type, then you can create an instance of that type. You can get the addtress of the instance, but not of a type. imagine the following: `int x;` you can get the address for variable `x`, but not for the type `int`

Comment: @user4581301: how do you think "they have size" and "do not require storage" go together? That size must go somewhere, be it in the code section of the DLL

Comment: A class (a type) just describes a thing. It has no size or representation it's just a blueprint. You can create *instances* of a type and those have sizes since they are actual things that exist - something concrete created from the class blueprint.

Comment: Thanks for responses but I'm still left with the same question: if I can get the value of "attr1" from "class1::attr1" and the address of attr1 from "&(class1::attr1)", then why can't I get the address of "class1"?

Comment: It seems to me that "class1" in "class1::attr1" is not being treated as a type... correct?

Comment: @GianPaolo: re: your point about `int`:

Immediate Window" "int" returns 
"type name is not allowed"

But as I pointed out in my question #3, "class1" return a blank line.  So this confuses me...

Comment: @SAbboushi `&(class1::attr1)` is a member pointer, which is distinct from a normal object pointer. It does not point to an actual object. It needs to be paired with a `class1*` pointer. Together it yields a pointer to the `attr1` member of the instance the `class*` pointer points to. In other words `&(class1::attr1)` is a pointer of sorts but not an object pointer and does not point to an address. Most likely it is represented as a memory offset.

Comment: >> and does not point to an address
>> It does not point to an actual object
@FrançoisAndrieux: if you look at my original post, you'll see that an address is returned.  Examining this address in a memory window shows the value of attr1 at that address.  The address is also the same as address returned by "this" (an actual object) which I think makes sense since attr1 is the first/only member.  This address is the same address as c1 object address (after execution returns to main()).

So it's still unclear to me what I am missing/misunderstanding...

Comment: @SAbboushi It isn't clear to me how you got that result. Maybe you used your debugging tools while your code was stopped within the context of a member function, and it assumed `this` as the associated object. But I can assure you that a pointer to member like `&(class1::attr1)` does not point to an object.

Comment: Thanks - if you look at the original post, you'll see where the breakpoint is/code was stopped.

Comment: @SAbboushi I'm not familiar with VS2019's debugger. Because a member pointer on its own the debugger probably assumes that you meant to use `this` with it. Try in `int main` and see if it changes.

Comment: After returning to `int main`, Immediate Window for "&(class1::attr1)" returns "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object"

To recap the questions/responses that to me are unresolved:
It seems that "class1" during the constructor is treated both as a type as evidenced by ```
&class1       (treats class1 as type)
type name is not allowed
```
and as a class as evidenced by
```
&(class1::attr1)
0x000000877f54fcf4 {0x0000000c}
```
where the address of object is returned as confirmed by "&c1" after object has been initialized.

Comment: if I can get the value of "attr1" from "class1::attr1" and the address of attr1 from "&(class1::attr1)", then why can't I get the address of "class1"?  Is there a way for me to qualify "class1" in debugger so that it treats it in the same way as it does in "&(class1::attr1)"?
And also, any explanation as to why "class1" value is returned as a blank line?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you wish to access the RTTI of the class.  Chances are, different compilers may implement it slightly differently to one another.

That said, there is an operator called `typeid`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Take a look at this blog for an example of using it with the Visual-C compiler:
https://blog.quarkslab.com/visual-c-rtti-inspection.html

which features this example:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass {};
class MyDerivedClass : public MyClass {};

template<typename T> void PrintTypeInformation(char const* pVarName, T const& t)
{
  std::cout
    << pVarName
    << ": type: "     << typeid(t).name()
    << ", raw type: " << typeid(t).raw_name()
    << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  MyClass cls;
  MyDerivedClass *drv;
  int n;
  char c;
  __int64 l;
  double d;

#define PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(var) PrintTypeInformation(#var, var)

  PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(cls);
  PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(drv);
  PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(n);
  PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(c);
  PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(&l);
  PRINT_TYPE_INFORMATION(d);

  return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
cls: type: class MyClass, raw type: .?AVMyClass@@
drv: type: class MyDerivedClass *, raw type: .PAVMyDerivedClass@@
n: type: int, raw type: .H
c: type: char, raw type: .D
&l: type: __int64 *, raw type: .PA_J
d: type: double, raw type: .N
```

---

If you're interested in accessing the debug information in the PDB file (MSVC) then take a look at the answers to this question:
[Do debugging information reveal code in C++ / MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406879/do-debugging-information-reveal-code-in-c-msvc)

Comment: Thanks @Den-Jason.  The info may give me clues on how to answer my question, but it's above my head...

Again my thanks to all.

It seems my question is highly implementation/debugger specific and the answer may be "when within class1 scope, VS debugger allows using class1 identifier for non-static member access of the object, but lacking an SRO, debugger treats class1 identifier as a type"